# lldb in xcode gives [no Objective-C description available] when trying to call the 'count' selector

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5, lldb

Hopefully my question is clear with the screen shot[image]

In the left pane, my variable `thing` is visible in the current breakpoint.

I would like to call some selectors on this variable in lldb

However when I do

```
(lldb) po [thing count]
```

It gives an 'no Objective-C description available' error message. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`po` is a shortcut for `expression -O  --`, which prints the description of
Objective-C objects.

But `[thing count]` returns an `NSUInteger`, which is a scalar and not an Objective-C object.

```
p [thing count]
```

or

```
p (NSUInteger) [thing count]
```

should work.

Comment: or you could `po @([thing count])` (wraps in NSNumber)